# How to have multiple filters work at the same time in one formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I'm trying to make a filtered list. The information in the list depends on if multiple values are check or not.

In image one you have the ranks which I want to have one filter. Then the training type and then the training style. So the filter hierarchy is Rank --> Training Type --> Training Style.

**Rank:**
So first I want it to filter my list with items (see image 2) based on the rank it has assigned. If multiple ranks are selected then I want it to included those multiple rank. the formula should always filter on rows and never on cells.

**Training Type:**
Then I want the list filtered based on rank to be filter again. But this time based on the Training Type. If possible with one formula. If not then 2 lists

**Training Style:**
Lastly I want it to filter the list that has been filtered on both rank and training type to filter on training style. This is one of three values.

**Output:**
I want a seperate output list. So I don't want my main list (see image 2) to be filtered.

**Training Routine:**
Finally I'm then trying to take that filtered list and output 5 random rows from that list when I click the "generate" button.

This is what I'm trying to do. My main problem right now is that I can't seem to find on how to filter on multiple criteria with a different output to make one list

[image: google sheet filter values]

[image: google sheets list that needs filtering]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/168586/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table with your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.